# How can I view a Microsoft Word document (doc/docx) within Firefox?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-word, php, html, documents

I have a small application with a directory that holds Word documents. I want to enable the user to view the documents within the browser. To have a list of the documents and when the users clicks on a document he will see the document on the right panel.

How can I view a Word document (doc/docx) inside Firefox?

I thought of a few options:

1. Convert the document to HTML - but it's too problematic and I need to hold both the original version and HTML version.
2. Use an extension - any ideas for such an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [this extension](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/10/29/firefox-add-on-download-thinkfree-viewer-to-view-any-document-without-installing-office-suite/).

The post is from 2008, but it does mention Firefox v3 so it might work with the latest versions of FF.

I've just checked and it doesn't work with FF 3.6.

Comment: Officially supported up to 3.6a, so update to 3.6 final is likely. Or add a boolean key with the following name, and a value of false: extensions.checkCompatibility.3.6

Comment: last updated Aug 2009 :-| (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9327)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the documents to PDF, and then use [Google's online PDF viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) to view them, this way the users don't need any special plugins installed.

Comment: Thanks. But since i don't want the documents to be avilable on the net nor to google, i need another solution. Any good idea how to convert the doc/x to pdf?

Comment: for converting to PDF, you can use a print driver like the free CutePDF Writer (http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) for Windows. You could also use OpenOffice and print to PDF. On Linux and Mac OS, printing or saving to PDF is a built-in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The method I use to convert my Docs is to [print to pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). Otherwise probably the closest you will get to open it in FF is to cheat and use [IE View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/35).

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand what you want.  You need the user can access a word or excel document within  the browser right ?

Is that only for access ?  Word buttons must be hidden (New, print, etc. ) ?

I think what you need is a viewer.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I need a doc/docx viewer inside the browser.